# Why ipython Anaconda does not recognize my omdb import?

Tags: python, terminal, anaconda

I am having some issues understanding what is happening with the installation of omdb module in my computer (https://github.com/dgilland/omdb.py).

I installed via Terminal using:

```
pip install omdb
```

Then I created a simple python script to test if it would import correctly:

```
import matplotlib
import omdb

print omdb.get(title='A Beautiful Mind', fullplot=True, tomatoes=True)
```

The script ran perfectly when I used python in terminal:

```
python movies.py
```

but then I tried to use my ipython with Anaconda, and I would always get the following message:

```
ImportError: no module named omdb
```

Is there another way to install a module, or am I missing something about Anaconda and Python?
All I wanted was to be able to use omdb. I'm using Python 2.7.11-0 and OS X 10.9.5. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because [Anaconda installed packages aren't stored into a Python library](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-install-Python-packages-in-Anaconda), it has it's own warehouse. So you should use [the command for it](http://conda.pydata.org/docs/using/index.html):

```
conda install omdb
```

> Anaconda comes with its own package manager named **conda**. It also doubles as a virtual environment manager.
>
> The Python package manager is **pip**, which is only a package manager and you will have to install **virtualenv** in order to manage virtual environments.